# Why does console.log return empty array in when using find method in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, backend

I am new to backend dev. I am trying to check if there is already an existing user in the collection and console log 'no' if there is none. I do not have the indicated data in 'const b' but instead of 'no' I keep getting empty array in terminal.

```
const b = {email: "xxx@mail.ru", password: "wwww"}
MyModel.find(b)
    .then(exUs =>{
        if(exUs){
            console.log(exUs)
        } else {
            console.log("no")
        }          
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` always returns an `cursor`(which can be empty `[]` if no docs) ,so your if condition will always true ,and if there are zero docs it will print empty array `[]` (returns cursor never null).

```
const b = {email: "xxx@mail.ru", password: "wwww"}
MyModel.find(b)
    .then(exUs =>{
        if(exUs){ // this always returns true even if there are no docs as empty array[]
            console.log(exUs)
        } else {
            console.log("no")
        }          
    })
```

What you should do rather ?

This

```
const b = {email: "xxx@mail.ru", password: "wwww"}
MyModel.find(b)
    .then(exUs =>{

        if(exUs.length>0){
            console.log(exUs)
        } else {
            console.log("no")
        }          
    })
```

Or You can use `findOne`,it will return `null` if no doc is found and the very first doc if exists ,so your code will become

```
const b = {email: "xxx@mail.ru", password: "wwww"}
MyModel.findOne(b)
    .then(exUs =>{
        if(exUs){// checks for null here now
            console.log(exUs)
        } else { 
            console.log("no")
        }          
    })
```